# Is this Chinese? If so can you tell me what it says in english? Thank you

Tags: translation

[image]
Is this Chinese?  If so can you tell me what it says in english?  Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Chinese (and it's written in Simplified Chinese).

"苹果" means "apple"; and "帝国" means "Empire". The whole phrase could be translated as "The Apple Empire" or "The Empire of Apple" into English.